# Concatenation in Shell Scripting Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I wanna check if 2 lines have equal $4 my shell must check if the diffrence between $3 in line 2 and $2 in line 3 is equal 1 it must concatenate both line into one like this

```
1;1000000000;1099999999;2
2;1100000000;1199999999;3
3;1200000000;1200004444;3
```

Output

```
1;1000000000;1099999999;2
2;1100000000;1200004444;3
```

I dont know even to use awk or something else

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? This is totally unclear: "I wanna check if 2 lines have equal $4 my shell must check..."

Comment: if there exist any 2 lines in my file having equal $4 (for example 3 in the above file line 2 and 3 have equal values )  I need to Concatenate them to something like the output

Comment: What about doing simply `sort -t';' -k4 -u file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -F';' -lane '
    if ($L[2] + 1 == $F[1] and $L[3] == $F[3]) {
        $L[2] = $F[2]
    } else {
        print join ";", @L if @L;
        @L = @F
    }
    END { print join ";", @L }
' file.csv
```

Comment: Please if i want to add another field at the beggining this filed is i which represent index and increments every line ??

Comment: @Mina: `++$i` increments the variable `$i` and returns its new value. Insert it as the second parameter to each `print join`.